# Render image tag in jsx throw exception in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I write next reactjs 0.13.2 class with jsx template

```
var ImageTest = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
         return {image:"https://pp.vk.me/c1432/g6369227/c_194fa45c.jpg"};
    },

    render: function () {
         return <img src={this.state.image}/>;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
   React.render(<ImageTest/>, document.getElementById('card'));
});
```

I worked in Intelj Idea and have File watcher. FW run Babel task for transform this file to clean JS. And this file worked in browser Chrome

```
"use strict";

var ImageTest = React.createClass({
    displayName: "ImageTest",

    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
        return { image: "https://pp.vk.me/c1432/g6369227/c_194fa45c.jpg" };
    },

    render: function render() {
        return React.createElement("img", { src: this.state.image });
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    React.render(React.createElement(ImageTest, null), document.getElementById("card"));
});
```

And throw next Exception on page load
Warning: Only functions or strings can be mounted as React components.
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
function autoGenerateWrapperClass(type) {
    return ReactClass.createClass({
    tagName: type.toUpperCase(),
     render: function() {
      return new ReactElement(
      type,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      this.props
     );
   }
 });
}
```

This function in Reactjs raise exception, row this type.toUpperCase(). For `img` type==Object, if use `<div>` type==div. Whats wrong in code?

Comment: Both your code snippets work for me https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/6790/ Could you try to reproduce your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: No, in fiddle work fine both. May be libraries conflict... Testing localy more

Comment: Yes, Vkontakte JavaScript SDK - //vk.com/js/api/xd_connection.js?2 conflict with reactjs

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you're exporting the right components in your modules. The error occurs when the component passed doesn't exist (undefined)